# ArcGIS Online and Nearmap Basemap Imagery

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-online, imagery, basemap, nearmap

I am trying to get an exported Nearmap imagery as my basemap for an ArcGIS Online map. I have the Nearmap Image and it's respective georeference file (JPG File and JGW File). Is there a way to upload this to ArcGIS Online and use it as my basemap?

Comment: Not sure what licensing agreement you have, but they offer a WMTS that has been tested off in ArcGIS Online.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a mosaic dataset from the images.
2. Generate a tile cache from the mosaic dataset using the Tile Cache toolset in ArcGIS for Desktop.
3. Package the tile cache
4. Upload the package to ArcGIS Online

**Check the license agreement with nearmap that you can share the image online** first.

https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/share-imagery-as-an-arcgis-online-tiled-map-service.htm

Comment: Thank you! Is there by chance any other way to do this? I do not currently have a standard or advanced license so I can not access the 'create mosaic dataset' option.

Comment: A related question that would be worth exploring, is whether QGIS (free GIS software) can produce a tile cache in a format that ArcGIS Online can use.

Comment: Sounds like there is only one JPG?  In which case you dont need to put it in a Mosaic Dataset and should be able to create a tile package with a basic license.